# NameError: uninitialized constant Innate::MiddlewareCompiler, using Compass/Sass

Tags: ruby, sass, drupal-7, gulp, zen

I'm trying to use sass to do some css updates on a site with a zen theme. I've installed all the latest gem on an ubuntu dev machine. I get the following error with the `compass watch` command:

```
NameError on line ["7"] of /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ramaze-2012.04.14/lib/ramaze/middleware_compiler.rb: uninitialized constant Innate::MiddlewareCompiler
Did you mean?  Innate::MIDDLEWARE
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this, or really what's causing it, and how do I get it to choose the right option. From my research, I have found that this seems to be a common issue withthe RAMAZE gem. They have some upgrading instructions, but none of them make any sense to me as I'm not sure where or how to specify the innate version, or how to make it pick the correct function. http://ramaze.net/documentation/file.upgrading.html.

Here's the trace from the compass watch command:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ramaze-2012.04.14/lib/ramaze/middleware_compiler.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ramaze-2012.04.14/lib/ramaze.rb:40:in `<module:Ramaze>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ramaze-2012.04.14/lib/ramaze.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/zen-0.4.3/lib/zen.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:179:in `require'
  /var/www/html/phisigmarho.org/sites/all/themes/psrmodern/config.rb:30:in `get_binding'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `eval'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `parse_string'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in `block in _parse'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `open'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `_parse'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in `block in new_from_file'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:207:in `with_defaults'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in `new_from_file'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:19:in `configuration_for'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:69:in `add_project_configuration'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:37:in `add_project_configuration'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:41:in `initialize'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `new'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `perform!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
```

Here's my gemlist, basically whatever gets sucked in from `gem install compass`

```
bcrypt (3.1.11)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5, 3.0.1)
bigdecimal (1.2.8)
bundler (1.13.2)
chunky_png (1.3.7)
compass (1.0.3)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
did_you_mean (1.0.2, 1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.2.5, 1.1.3)
ffi (1.9.14)
innate (2015.10.28)
io-console (0.4.6, 0.4.5)
json (2.0.2, 1.8.3)
loofah (2.0.3, 1.2.1)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.9.1, 5.8.4)
multi_json (1.12.1)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.6.8.1)
power_assert (0.3.1, 0.2.7)
psych (2.1.1, 2.0.17)
rack (2.0.1, 1.6.4)
rake (11.3.0, 10.5.0, 0.9.2.2)
ramaze (2012.12.08, 2012.04.14)
ramaze-asset (0.2.3)
rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
rb-inotify (0.9.7)
rdoc (4.2.2, 4.2.1)
sass (3.4.22)
sass-globbing (1.1.5)
sequel (4.39.0, 3.35.0)
shebang (0.1)
test-unit (3.2.1, 3.1.7)
zen (0.4.3)
zen-grids (2.0.3)
```

I'm beginning to suspect that maybe rolling back to an earlier version of compass, but I don't that that will resolve whatever dependency conflict this is triggering.

Comment: This issue is within your ruby code. I think you should post more of the stacktrace and a little bit of your ruby code where this exception occours.

Comment: so, the trace super long, to the point where I can't grab it all from the terminal.

Comment: What does your Gemfile/Gemspec look like?

Comment: Hi Scott, there's the gem file, what do you mean by gem spec

Comment: Yeah, I'm having exactly same error. I'm using gulp-compass to compile sass stylesheets built with the use of zen-grids. Did you perhaps solved the issue yourself?

Comment: Hi, not exactly for myself, but from my research, I think you should be able to get by with libsass and using the node-compass-mixins extension. That should get you compass and sass working without ruby.